# Mercury mail and php email creation script

Tags: php, html, email, wamp

I need help creating a script or program that can add users to my mercury mail server when they sign up on a form. I'm using a basic php post form, it does create all the necessary files to run the account but when I open mercury mail the new user account has not been added to the accounts list. And the new account cannot sign in.

Please assist me in creating a client email signup script or program so that my clients can easily create an email on my server for free.

Link to the form code: http://pastebin.com/bEtv4eck

Link to the php post code: http://pastebin.com/rwBJatap

P.S. I have the script working to where it can create the new user and everything, but it won't allow a login unless the email server is restarted. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the RELOAD USERS after making the changes to the pmail.usr and mail, directories.

Comment: RELOAD USERS? how do i make it do that?

Comment: i'm using the script provided here: http://community.pmail.com/files/folders/community_add-ons_for_mercury/entry17424.aspx
but when it tries sending the mail inside the script it says failed in the mercury mail software system

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add user in the `PMAIL.USR` file

Try

```
const MERCURY_PATH = 'C:\Apache\xampp\MercuryMail';
$userFile = MERCURY_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "PMAIL.USR";
$mailDir = MERCURY_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "MAIL";

$newName = "Baba Konko";
$newUsername = "baba";
$newPassword = "pass";
$host = "localhost";

if (! is_writeable ( $userFile )) {
    die ( "You don't have permission to  Create new User" );
}

if (! is_writeable ( $mailDir )) {
    die ( "You don't have permission to add mail folder" );
}

// Check if user exist

if (is_file ( $userFile )) {
    $users = file ( $userFile );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        list ( $status, $username, $name ) = explode ( ";", strtolower ( $user ) );

        if (strtolower ( $newUsername ) == $username) {
            die ( "User Already Exist" );
        }
    }
}

$userData = "U;$newUsername;$newName";
$fp = fopen ( $userFile, "a" );

if ($fp) {
    fwrite ( $fp, $userData . chr ( 10 ) );
    fclose ( $fp );
}

$folder = $mailDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newUsername;
if (! mkdir ( $folder )) {
    die ( "Error Creating Folder" );
}

$pm = '# Mercury/32 User Information File' . chr ( 10 );
$pm .= 'POP3_access: ' . $newPassword . chr ( 10 );
$pm .= 'APOP_secret: ' . $newPassword . chr ( 10 );

$pmFile = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PASSWD.PM';
file_put_contents ( $pmFile, $pm );
```

Comment: i already have the script adding the user to the PMAIL.USR file and it creates the users account, but it doesnt show up in mercury mail itself. the only way to make it show up is to restart the program. and i cannot sit there and keep closing and re opening the program all day. Any ideas on this?